# pythonで1文にfor in が多重ループになっている場合の解釈は？

Tags: python, matlab

現在pythonのコードをmatlabに変換しています。以下のコードの解釈がよく分かりませんので、教えていただけると幸いです。コードの内容はrecursive bisectionとなります。

```
cItems=[8,1,9,7,4,6,3,5,0,2]

cItems=[i[j:k]for i in cItems for j,k in ((0,len(i)/2),(len(i)/2,len(i))) if len(i)>1]
```

でcItemsの一文をforループで分解してmatlabコードに変換したいのですが、この部分のpython のコードがtrickyに組まれておりよく分かりません。ご存知の方いらしましたらご教授ください。

Comment: 上記のコードではlen(i)/2をint(len(i)/2)としないとエラーになるようです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

提示されたコードは動作しませんでした。

とりあえず、文法で解釈して単純に展開すると以下のようになります。
元のコードはPython2向けのようなので、Python3向けの修正も入れます。

```
cItems = [8,1,9,7,4,6,3,5,0,2]

cItems2 = []
for i in cItems:
    for j,k in [(0, len(i)//2), (len(i)//2, len(i))]:
        if len(i) > 1:
            cItems2.append(i[j:k])
```

もうちょっと展開します

```
cItems = [8,1,9,7,4,6,3,5,0,2]

cItems2 = []
for i in cItems:
    if len(i) > 1:
        j = 0
        k = len(i) // 2
        cItems2.append(i[j:k])

        j = len(i) // 2
        k = len(i)
        cItems2.append(i[j:k])
```

展開方法はこんな感じです。
元コードの正しく動作するものがあれば、同じように展開して構造を理解できるかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。私の方での実行結果を記載しておきますので、参考にいただければ幸いです。

Comment: >>cItems =[8,1,9,7,4,6,3,5,0,2] から 実行後は >> cItems =[ [8,1,9,7,4],[6,3,5,0,2]]と配列が2分されていました。

Answer (score 0):

recursive bisection という名前から察すると、データの指定が違ってると思います。

```
cItems=[[8,1,9,7,4,6,3,5,0,2]]
cItems=[i[j:k]for i in cItems for j,k in ((0,len(i)/2),(len(i)/2,len(i))) if len(i)>1]
```

これを実行すると

```
[[8, 1, 9, 7, 4], [6, 3, 5, 0, 2]]
```

更に実行すると

```
[[8, 1], [9, 7, 4], [6, 3], [5, 0, 2]]
```

更に実行すると

```
[[8], [1], [9], [7, 4], [6], [3], [5], [0, 2]]
```

更に実行すると

```
[[7], [4], [0], [2]]
```

更に実行すると

```
[]
```

最初の内包表記に適切に改行をいれると読みやすくなります。

```
cItems=[i[j:k]                               # 最終的に並べる項目
        for i in cItems                      # 1番目に行うfor文
        for j, k in ((0, len(i) / 2),        # 2番目に行うfor文、1つ目の j, k
                     (len(i) / 2, len(i)))   #                   2つ目の j, k
        if len(i) > 1]                       # 3番目に行うif文
```